# why struct arrays comparing has different result

Tags: arrays, pointers, go, struct, compare

I don't know why the below happens, and I can't find source code relative. Can anybody explain to me?

```
var s, ss struct{} // two empty structs
arr1 := [6]*struct{}{&s} // array with empty struct pointer
arr2 := [6]*struct{}{&ss} // array with empty struct pointer
fmt.Println(&s == &ss, arr1 == arr2)  // false, true

var l, ll struct{A int}{}
arr3 := [6]*struct{A int}{&l} // array with empty struct pointer
arr4 := [6]*struct{A int}{&ll} // array with empty struct pointer
fmt.Println(&l == &ll, arr3 == arr4)  // false, false
```

Comment: doesn't print(&s) give you a memory addres and print(arr1) a value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Spec: Comparison operators:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators)

> Pointer values are comparable. Two pointer values are equal if they point to the same variable or if both have value `nil`. **Pointers to distinct [zero-size](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees) variables may or may not be equal.**

And also [Spec: Size and alignment guarantees:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees)

> A struct or array type has size zero if it contains no fields (or elements, respectively) that have a size greater than zero. Two distinct zero-size variables **may** have the same address in memory.

Size of the `s` and `ss` variables are zero, so `&s` and `&ss` are pointers to distinct zero-size variables, so the spec does not guarantee anything about their equality. What this means is that `&s == &ss` may evaluate to either `true` or `false`, you can't count on what the result will be, and it would be a mistake to do so.

Still, it is weird that during a single runtime of the app, once they are equal, and once they are not. Lesson is to not rely on it, ever.

The different behavior can be explained by looking at the escape analysis.

Let's simplify your app to this:

```
var s, ss struct{}                   // two empty structs
arr1 := [6]*struct{}{&s}             // array with empty struct pointer
arr2 := [6]*struct{}{&ss}            // array with empty struct pointer
fmt.Println(&s == &ss, arr1 == arr2) // false, true
```

Running the escape analysis with `go run -gcflags '-m' play.go` gives:

```
./play.go:13:17: &s == &ss escapes to heap
./play.go:13:30: arr1 == arr2 escapes to heap
./play.go:11:23: main &s does not escape
./play.go:12:23: main &ss does not escape
./play.go:13:14: main &s does not escape
./play.go:13:20: main &ss does not escape
./play.go:13:13: main ... argument does not escape
false true
```

`&s` and `&ss` do not escape (as they are not passed to `fmt.Println()`, only the result of `&s == &ss`).

If we add a single line to the above simplified app:

```
var s, ss struct{}                   // two empty structs
arr1 := [6]*struct{}{&s}             // array with empty struct pointer
arr2 := [6]*struct{}{&ss}            // array with empty struct pointer
fmt.Println(&s == &ss, arr1 == arr2) // true, true

fmt.Printf("%p %p\n", &s, &ss) // true, true
```

Running escape analysis now gives:

```
./play.go:13:17: &s == &ss escapes to heap
./play.go:13:30: arr1 == arr2 escapes to heap
./play.go:15:24: &s escapes to heap
./play.go:15:24: &s escapes to heap
./play.go:10:6: moved to heap: s
./play.go:15:28: &ss escapes to heap
./play.go:15:28: &ss escapes to heap
./play.go:10:9: moved to heap: ss
./play.go:11:23: main &s does not escape
./play.go:12:23: main &ss does not escape
./play.go:13:14: main &s does not escape
./play.go:13:20: main &ss does not escape
./play.go:13:13: main ... argument does not escape
./play.go:15:12: main ... argument does not escape
true true
```

The behavior changed: we now see `true true` output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6aGn3RZTmL2)).

The reason for the changed behavior is because `&s` and `&ss` escape to heap: they are directly passed to `fmt.Println()`, so the compiler changed how (where) they are stored, and with that, so did their address.

See related / possible duplicate: [Golang Address of Slices of Empty Structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052722/golang-address-of-slices-of-empty-structs/48053270#48053270)

Comment: thx for your detailed reply. i would find something about the escape to heap to have a better understand.   thx again..