# Why does the Go compiler do this optimization

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := new(struct{})
    b := new(struct{})
    println(a, b, a==b)

    c := new(struct{})
    d := new(struct{})
    fmt.Println(c, d, c==d)
}
```

output:

```
0xc000107f37 0xc000107f37 false
&{} &{} true
```

And, I will get different results after disabling compiler optimization.

```
0xc000087e4e 0xc000087e4e true
&{} &{} true
```

Why does the Go compiler do this optimization?

See [this line in the runtime source code ]

(https://github.com/golang/go/blob/6317adeed7815ad335e2e97c463a7c3c4d82fc19/src/runtime/malloc.go#L586)

```
    if size == 0 {
        return unsafe.Pointer(&zerobase)
    }
```

I think that since all zero-size variables will be allocated with zerobase, it should print true instead of false.

Comment: There's no need to allocate space for a value with zero size. The [specification says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees): *Two distinct zero-size variables may have the same address in memory.*   See [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052722/addresses-of-slices-of-empty-structs), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421103/why-struct-arrays-comparing-has-different-result?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @CeriseLimón - The question is why does `a==b` print `false` with optimizations

Comment: From the spec: "Pointer values are comparable. Two pointer values are equal if they point to the same variable or if both have value nil. Pointers to distinct zero-size variables **may or may not** be equal." (emphasize mine). The compiler is free to report true or false and takes this liberty to do so.

Comment: @slebetman  It looks like the optimizer replaced the call to the allocation function with inline code and that inline code does not use `zerobase`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Then that's the answer. Actually I think Volker's comment is the actual answer and the inline thing explains why it happens. The key is the spec says "may have" instead of "will have"

Comment: See related question [Go lang empty struct confusing feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62155916/go-lang-empty-struct-confusing-feature).