# Go lang empty struct confusing feature

Tags: go, struct, compiler-optimization

Here is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct{}

func main() {
    var ad, bd A
    res1 := &ad == &bd
    res2 := ad == bd
    fmt.Println(res1, res2)// true true
    fmt.Printf("%p, %p\n", &ad, &bd) // 0x57bb60, 0x57bb60
}
```

Now if I comment the last line of main function like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct{}

func main() {
    var ad, bd A
    res1 := &ad == &bd
    res2 := ad == bd
    fmt.Println(res1, res2) // false true
    //fmt.Printf("%p, %p\n", &ad, &bd)
}
```

The program prints `false true`!

How can the last line influence the output?
Is there any special feature with the empty struct?
Or this problem is caused by the compiler?

Comment: Empty structs are zero-sized, and per the spec _may_ be placed at the same memory location. Printing its address may influence where it's placed since that may make the value escape to heap.

Comment: Nobody uses empty structs except for simulating set types for really _very_ **large** sets (or because people want to be clever).