# Most efficient way to create a unique map key in Go

Tags: go

I have a `map[any]SomeType` somewhere in a library. I want library users to be able to create keys for that map such that they are guaranteed to not collide within a single application execution, and I want these keys to be efficient for map lookup.

The first thing that comes to mind is to use a memory address of some unique empty object. But everything I tried failed so far:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

var key1 = &struct{}{}
var key2 = &struct{}{}

var key3 = struct{}{}
var key4 = struct{}{}

var key5 = new(struct{})
var key6 = new(struct{})

func main() {
    fmt.Println("key1 == key2", key1 == key2)
    fmt.Println("key3 == key4", &key3 == &key4)
    fmt.Println("key5 == key6", key5 == key6)
    test(key1, key2, "func12")
    test(&key3, &key4, "func34")
    test(key5, key6, "func56")
}

func test(a, b any, msg string) {
    fmt.Println(msg, a == b)
}
```

prints

```
key1 == key2 true
key3 == key4 false
key5 == key6 true
func12 true
func34 true
func56 true
```

So taking an address of an empty struct variable almost works, until you pass it into a function. Then distinction vanishes.

I don't want to introduce a key registry because it is an unnecessary complication. I also don't really want to use strings, because then different consumers of the library need to negotiate keys or use namespaces, and the need to hash and compare strings is also an unnecessary complication.

Is there a way I didn't think of?

Comment: The spec permits to use the same address for distinct, zero-sized variables. An empty struct has zero size, so whether 2 of them has the same address may or may not be true. Do not use zero-value types or values for the map keys! See [Addresses of slices of empty structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052722/addresses-of-slices-of-empty-structs/48053270#48053270); and [why struct arrays comparing has different result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421103/why-struct-arrays-comparing-has-different-result/52421277#52421277)

Comment: You may provide a `NewKey() int64` function returning incremental values. No need to store previously handed out keys, you will not run out of the valid range (and start repeating values) during the lifetime of the app: that would require 292 years if you could hand out 1 key in every nanosecond!

Comment: Just use 1, 2, 3…. as keys. Your question makes little sense to me (apart from the obvious mistake with empty struct address).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library uses a "trick" when working with `context.Context`: contexts are able to carry arbitrary values in them, and these values are keyed using `interface{}` (`any` since some time)¹. Then your own package can define a new unexported type for their context keys it's going to use and then define a set of constants having that type to serve as the context keys known to that package. Now the trick is that a type is always a part of any value of type `interface{}`, so it's impossible to create an interface value which would clash with your package's keys.

Basically, something like this:

```golang
package mypkg

type contextKey int

const (
  KeyFoo = contextKey(iota)
  KeyBar
)
```

Now when you do `key interface{} = KeyFoo`, it's pretty much guaranteed no other piece of any code in a program can have the same value as `key` has because a part of it will be (an internal pointer to the) unexported type `contextKey`.
You might want read [this classic piece](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces) to understand how this works (it's a bit rusty but still 99% true).

To me, it looks like a way forward: the users of your package can generate their own keys and submit it to your map which should have `interface{}` or `any` as the type of its keys. There will be no need to have a centralized registry handing off these keys.

---

¹ See [context.Context.Value()](https://pkg.go.dev/context#Context) and [context.WithValue()](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithValue) for more info. The latter gives more hints on how to generate keys.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the solution I missed. I knew `interface{}` carried the type. I also knew `type Foo int` introduced a distinct type. But my Go was as rusty as that article you mentioned, so I failed to put one and one together. :D